# How to decrypt data in Java that was encrypted by PHP method openssl_encryp aes-256-cbc?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String iv = "0102030405060708";
    String key = "1882051051AgVfZUKJLInUbWvOPsAP6LM6nBwLn14140722186";

    byte[] aaa = AES_cbc_decrypt("hv208Otx0FZL32GUuErHDLlZzC3zVEGRt56f8lviQpk=", key, iv);
    System.out.println(new String(aaa));
}

private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

public static byte[] AES_cbc_decrypt(String content,String key,String iv) throws Exception 
{
    byte[] contentBytes = Base64.decode(content);
    byte[] keyBytes = key.substring(0, 16).getBytes();
    byte[] ivBytes = iv.getBytes();

    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
    byte[] decbbdt = cipher.doFinal(contentBytes);
    return decbbdt;
}
```

run with this code and i get the follow exception :

> Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

it can be decrypt by php method

```
openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encryptData), 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

Comment: Why reducing the key from 50 bytes to 16? AFAIK in php it is denoted as password not key, which means that that it can be of any length and a key derivation function is used for generating the real key.

Comment: You need to show your complete php code. It's not clear how key and IV are actually decoded.

Comment: Never use `String#getBytes` without an argument, because the default character set might change between different systems.

Answer (score 1):

You try to decrypt with a key of 16 bytes or 128 bits. However, you have been using AES-256 where 256 denotes the key size: 32 bytes of course.

Now C and C-libraries such as OpenSSL generally use pointer arithmetic to determine the amount of bytes. When specifying the key they generally take a pointer address and an amount of bytes (or for lower level libraries, 32 bit words, etc.)

So in all likelihood when specifying a key larger than 32 characters / bytes this key is cut down to 32 bytes (or `char`s in C, where bytes and characters are for ever confused). However in your Java code you cut down the key to 16 bytes. This would lead to using AES-256 in C and AES-128 in Java.

---

Moral of the story: don't confuse passwords / strings and keys.